# How to retrieve a subset of columns in a foreign-key relationship in Entity Framework with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have an ordinary foreign-key column like this:

```
[Table("Thing")]
public class Thing
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? StatusId { get; set; }

    // want to omit this potentially large object
    [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
    public ThingStatus Status { get; set; } 

    // This column isn't in the Thing table; how to best populate it from ThingStatus?
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    ...
}


[Table("ThingStatus")]
public class ThingStatus {...}
```

Now let us suppose ThingStatus has lots of columns, more than I want.  Is there a slick way to retrieve only some of the values via the model annotations ?   Instead of having a navigation property to ThingStatus, is there a way to tell EF to retrieve only ThingStatus.Name for my property StatusName, for example?

Assuming there's not, is there a more elegant way to get this than retrieving from ThingStatus via .Select and mapping it in code?

Comment: The answer is: no. But that's too short to post as a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the desired effect by selecting an object.  EF will only return what you tell it to select.

```
var results = myContext.Things
    .Select(x => new ThingViewModel()
    {
        StatusName = x.ThingStatus.Name
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Sure, that's the option that seems less elegant than I might imagine.  I was curious if there was a way to do this via DataAnnotations in my model classes.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski What's so inelegant about it?  Doing this is a known pattern.

Comment: Sure, but I have to specify it every place I retrieve this data, rather than in my model once for all.